# using buttons for countdown timer in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer, but i cant realized how to put a button to start/stop the countdown. I was trying to create the method inside the onCreate method but it returns an error, so my script its like this (where goButton is my onClick function):

```
package com.example.ricardofonzo.eggtimer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mplayer;

int estadoContador =0;

public void goButton(View view){
    estadoContador = 1;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bell);

    final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView);

    CountDownTimer cuentaRegresiva = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long segundos = millisUntilFinished/1000;
            long minutos;
            if (segundos>= 60) {
                minutos = segundos / 60;
                segundos = segundos - minutos * 60;
                if (minutos > 9) {
                    if (segundos > 9) {
                        timeView.setText(String.valueOf(minutos) + ":" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    } else {
                        timeView.setText(String.valueOf(minutos) + ":0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (segundos > 9) {
                        timeView.setText("0" + String.valueOf(minutos) + ":" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    } else {
                        timeView.setText("0" + String.valueOf(minutos) + ":0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (segundos>9){
                    timeView.setText("00:" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                } else {
                    timeView.setText("00:0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeView.setText("Time out!");
            mplayer.start();

        }
    }.start();

}
}
```

This is what i have at the moment. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: `but it returns an error` Which error?

Comment: the editor said that it was expecting a ";" instead of "(View view)". I already solve it but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `XML` file add this line to your button

```
android:onClick="startCounterDown"
```

and add this method to your activity

```
public void startCounterDown(View view){

    CountDownTimer cuentaRegresiva = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long segundos = millisUntilFinished/1000;
            long minutos;
            if (segundos>= 60) {
                minutos = segundos / 60;
                segundos = segundos - minutos * 60;
                if (minutos > 9) {
                    if (segundos > 9) {
                        timeView.setText(String.valueOf(minutos) + ":" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    } else {
                        timeView.setText(String.valueOf(minutos) + ":0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (segundos > 9) {
                        timeView.setText("0" + String.valueOf(minutos) + ":" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    } else {
                        timeView.setText("0" + String.valueOf(minutos) + ":0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (segundos>9){
                    timeView.setText("00:" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                } else {
                    timeView.setText("00:0" + String.valueOf(segundos));
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeView.setText("Time out!");
            mplayer.start();

        }
    }.start();


}
```

Comment: It works perfect. I created a new method in the mainActivity, not in the onCreate method and it works great. thanks!!